# Rails: How to create search-adding form

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm building a nested form with Cocoon. And the data source is users.
I try to build a search-adding form from select form. I want to let users search users and add that here.

```
<div class="formField">
  <%= f.collection_select :user_id, User.all, :id, :username %>
</div>
```

Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "search-adding form"? It's not quite clear in the question if you're talking about nested Cocoon inputs, a type-ahead select/search input, or some combination of both.

Comment: Sorry I want to develop the form to select a user via searching form. Do you know anything good example?

Comment: It's might be a bottleneck when you have a lot of users. It will take a lot of time to get users from the database. 

You can look at https://selectize.github.io/selectize.js/ and https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/ - ajax section.

Comment: Thanks a lot, finally I used Bootstrap select 2.